# Setting 'UserAccountControl' using Powershell and .NET

Tags: .net, powershell, adsi

I'm writing a Powershell script to create a user account in Active Directory, and I want to use credentials to do it, so I am using .NET

```
$objDirectoryEntry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ($OU,$($Credential.UserName),$($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().password))
$Account = $objDirectoryEntry.psbase.get_children().add("CN="+$AccountName,"User")
$Account.psbase.InvokeSet("sAMAccountName",$sAMAccountName)
$Account.psbase.invokeset("DisplayName", $Displayname)
$Account.psbase.invokeset("Description", $Description)
$Account.psbase.CommitChanges()
```

it seems impossible to set the infamous 'UserAccountControl' parameter

```
$Account.psbase.invokeset(“userAccountControl”, 66048) #fails
$Account.psbase.invokeset(“userAccountControl”, 0x10200) #fails
$Account.psbase.invokeset(“userAccountControl”, 0x2) #fails
```

On the other hand using the ADSI wrapper works fine.

```
$objADSI = [ADSI]$AdminOU
$objAccount = $objADSI.create("User","CN="+$AccountName)

# Create the account
$objAccount.put("SamAccountName", $AccountName)
$objAccount.put("DisplayName", $Displayname)
$objAccount.put("Description", $Description)
$objAccount.SetInfo()

# set password
$objAccount.SetPassword($AdminAccountPassword)
$objAccount.SetInfo()

# set the userAccountControl
$objAccount.put(“userAccountControl”, 66048)
$objAccount.SetInfo()
```

But cannot get ADSI wrapper method to run under different credentials.

Spend way too much time banging my head on this one, the only other methods I can think of is to start save the ADSI method to a external script and invoke it using credentials, surely theres a way

Comment: does it give you an error when it fails? and have you tired setting it to the actual int value: `512 (active) 514 (disabled) etc.`

Comment: Hi Dane, thanks for replying

Comment: Yes, here are commands I have tried and the errors recieved below

$ServerAccount.psbase.invokeset(“userAccountControl”, 512)
$ServerAccount.psbase.CommitChanges()
Exception calling "CommitChanges" with "0" argument(s): "The server is unwilling to process the request

Comment: $ServerAccount.psbase.invokeset(“userAccountControl”, 0x512)
$ServerAccount.psbase.CommitChanges()
Exception calling "CommitChanges" with "0" argument(s): "A device attached to the system is not functioning.

Comment: _Strangely enough this actually runs through without an error 'but' it does not appear to change anything in Active Directory?_

$ServerAccount.psbase.invokeset(“userAccountControl”, 0x2)
$ServerAccount.psbase.CommitChanges()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an easy way to get credentials into the powershell ADSI wrapper.

```
$objADSI = [ADSI]$LDAPPath
$objADSI.PsBase.Username = $UserName
$objADSI.PsBase.Password = $Password
```

Use *psbase* to expose hidden attributes of *System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry* .NET object

You can then return to the usual powershell ADSI wrapper methods and it all works well.